# Rep privilleges issue when creating account

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have a 200+ rep account in a site (Stack overflow), I created accounts in Stack Exchange and Cooking, the rep. goes to 101 correctly but I don't get the privilleges (I can't answer a protected question). I think that is that particullary privillage, I could have answered some good question, but instead I had to add comments couse of this privillage problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct.

Protected questions are protected to avoid drive-by answers/votes by people who are not already contributors to the site.

You will note that the protected message tells you that you need to **earn** 10 rep on the site. The association bonus is not earning rep on the site, just getting it from contributions **elsewhere**:

> #### [Remove New User Restrictions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)
>
> […]
>   Note that one needs to earn 10 rep on the site to be able to answer a protected question. **The association bonus does not count.**

Comment: How so? One good answer (on any non protected question) or question or 5 accepted suggested edits. Not that difficult.

Comment: I think @Ale is referring to the wording. In such case do you have a better suggestion in mind?